# How can I create a queue for jobs of a workflow in Github Actions triggered by different PRs?

Tags: github, github-actions

We are using Github Actions for our CI jobs, but when we have new commits to the different PRs, all of them trigger the CI workflow and we get many parallel executions of the workflow. The expected behavior would be to have a maximum of 2 or 3 parallel executions and a queue that then starts the jobs triggered by other PRs as soon as one of them finishes.

Using the concurrency setting doesn't work for this case, because it cancels other executions.

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure I understand well. Are you trying to run only one execution of the workflow per PR or?

Comment: Not really, what I want is that the different executions (from different PRs) are queued and executed according to this queue. Let's say we have PR's #1, #2, #3, #4:

PRs 1# triggers the workflow and soon after PR #2 and #3 also trigger it, followed closely by PR #4. What I want is:
executions form PR #1 and #2 start and the executions from #3 and #4 keep silently waiting.  As soon as the execution from #1 finishes, the one from #3 starts and #4 keeps waiting. when the execution from #2 finishes, #4 starts... and so on.

This way I'll always have just 2 parallel executions.